# Creating rows of a table in a for loop in jsp

Tags: loops, jsp, for-loop, html-table

In a jsp I have a table whose rows I am creating in a loop like this,

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Item</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Total</th>
<th>Actions</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<%
String[] cartItems = (String[]) request.getSession().getAttribute("cartList");
for (int i = 0; i < cartItems.length; i++) {
%>
   <td>
      <input type="text" id="itemPrice" maxlength="5" size="5" style="border:none;" value="$<%= cartItem[3]%>" />
   </td>
<% } %>
</tr>
</table>
```

Suppose 5 such rows are added, every row will have the id=itemPrice, but I want the rows to have:

```
id=itemPrice1
id=itemPrice2.. and so on..
```

How do I do this? Please help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="itemPrice<%=i%>" maxlength="5" size="5" style="border:none;" value="$<%= cartItem[3]%>" />
```

Note what happened with the "id". It's just the counter in the for sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this should work (not tested):

Replace `id="itemPrice"` with `id="itemPrice${i+1}"`

This way, you're inserting value of `i` inside of your html.

If this doesn't work, try `id="itemPrice<%=i+1%>"`.