# Get data using object array

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java add all table data into list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108960/java-add-all-table-data-into-list)

```
+--------+-------+-----+
|  Name  |number |qty  |
+--------+-------+-----+
|   ab   |   5   |  7  |
+--------+-------+-----+ 
|   cd   |   1   |  6  |
+--------+-------+-----+ 
|   ef   |   0   |  9  |
+--------+-------+-----+ 
|   gh   |   8   |  2  |
+--------+-------+-----+
```

I add all data in Product to Array List as shown below

```
public List<Product> search(){
    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
    ResultSet rs = DAO.fetch("SELECT * FROM Products");
    while (rs.next()) {
        product = new Product();
        product.setNumber(rs.getString("ProductNumber"));
        product.setName(rs.getString("ProductName"));
        product.setQty(rs.getString("ProductQty"));
        products.add(product);
    }
    return products;
}
```

How do i print all names in my jsp by using this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Comment: `5 min` Before you asked the `same question` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108960/java-add-all-table-data-into-list

Comment: @AmitD not **exactly** the same question, at least he made the effort to reuse the code I provided in my answer :)

Comment: @AmalPrasad You should try before asking. Show us you current JSP code, so that we can have a look at it and help you fix it.

Comment: No. You can not try and fail in 5 min. You need to try more. Edison tried 6000 times before finding correct filament ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the list by saying the below statement in the controller

```
List <Product> products = dao.search();
request.setAttribute("Products", products);
```

And, in your JSP you can use the following code (I am considering you know how to use include JSTL Libraries on your JSP Page).

For using the JSTL Core library, you will need to add the below line in your JSP

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

And then you can display the traverse the passed list to display all the products.

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Number</th>
     <th>Quantity</th>
   </tr>
 <c:forEach items="${Products}" var="product">
    <tr>
      <td><c:out value="${product.name}" /></td>
      <td><c:out value="${product.number}" /></td>
      <td><c:out value="${product.qty}" /></td>
    </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You will need to add the JSTL Library Jars on your classpath. If you are using some IDE like Eclipse/Netbeans etc, you can directly include the JAR, otherwise you will have to download the jar. http://findjar.com/jar/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar.html

Comment: You also require some `td` elements for the rows. This would otherwise be invalid markup (see my answer)

Comment: @btiernay I forgot to add them, thanks for the correction. Edited my answer.

Comment: how do i use '_List<Product> products = dao.search();_' instead of this request.setAttribute("Products", REFERENCE.search());

Comment: I was directly calling it without using a reference. You are also doing fine. You can set it like 
List<Product> products = dao.search();
request.setAttribute("Products", products);

Comment: I have edited my answer to include your search call.

Comment: @Vivek every this is working fine it's showing 3 empty tables why is that? I have getName and setName inside product

Comment: @AmalPrasad I didn't get your point. 3 Empty Tables? You mean 3 cells are empty for the name column?

Answer (score 0):

Add `products` to an [appropriate scope](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbk.html) and forward to your jsp page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
...
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
            <tr>
                <td>${product.name}</td>
                <td>${product.number}</td>
                <td>${product.qty}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

As an aside, it's beneficial to use [thead and tbody](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3) in such situations since:

> This division enables user agents to support scrolling of table bodies
>   independently of the table head and foot. When long tables are
>   printed, the table head and foot information may be repeated on each
>   page that contains table data.

Comment: cant we do this without JSTL?

Comment: @AmalPrasad See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645708/creating-rows-of-a-table-in-a-for-loop-in-jsp for an example

Comment: @AmalPrasad: The JSTL is to a JSP developer what a hammer is to a carpenter. Take some time to learn it: it's an essential tool.

Comment: @JBNizet But i'm not allowed to use libs because this is my class work if any one know how to do that?